# Finding and replacing #N/A with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert the #N/A errors created by an Xlookup.

The problem is that it gives me type mismatch error when a cell contains #N/A.

This is the code that gives me the error on the If line:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming data starts from row 2, adjust if needed
        If ws.Cells(i, 3).value = "DS De-scoped" Or IsError(ws.Cells(i, 3).value) Then
            ' Put '-- in all cells from D to L
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 4), ws.Cells(i, 12)).value = "--"
            
            ' In D and M, put "DS"
            ws.Cells(i, 4).value = "DS"
            ws.Cells(i, 13).value = "DS"
        End If
Next i
```

Comment: Please edit your question so all code is formatted as it should

Comment: I do not see an Xlookup in your code

Comment: what if you change  "--"  to "xx"

Comment: @BartMcEndree the Xlookup it's relevant only because I know where the #N/A is produced and is a true error (not a text value)

Comment: @RedHare the error comes in the second line of the code

Comment: The problem is `If ws.Cells(i, 3).value = "DS De-scoped"`. You can't compare an error value to a `String`. One option is to split the `If` into two checks: first for an error, then for `"DS De-scoped"`, as the posted answer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like so:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim hit As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    lastRow = 5
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow    ' Assuming data starts from row 2, adjust if needed
        hit = False
        If IsError(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
            hit = True
        ElseIf ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "DS De-scoped" Then
            hit = True
        End If
        If hit Then
            ' Put '-- in all cells from D to L
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 4), ws.Cells(i, 12)).Value = "--"

            ' In D and M, put "DS"
            ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "DS"
            ws.Cells(i, 13).Value = "DS"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It gives me the same error because I think you cannot convert a real #N/A into a text format

Comment: I've changed the code

Comment: But if you use XLOOKUP, you can avoid errors by filling in the fourth argument of the function.

Comment: I tested this code with a cell containing the=NA() formula and one with the DS... string, worked just fine. Not sure why it fails for you